# How to compare float in logstash?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

It's the pipeline config for test:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/tmp/test1.log"
  }
}
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}

output {
  if [a] == 1.1 {
    stdout {}
  }
}
```

I echo some test log to logfile:

```
echo '{"a": 1.1,"b": "test"}' >> /tmp/test1.log
```

But there isn't any output in console, and I try use the condition if [a] == "1.1" either not work.

Somebody know how to compare float?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you can use custom Ruby code to compare float:

```
ruby {
    code=> '
        if event.get("[a]") == 1.1 
            event.set("isFloat", "true")
        end
        '
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a good way to sovle question. but I used a stupid way to do this before you answered me:
mutate {
      add_field => { "tmp" => "%{a}" }"
      convert => { "tmp" => "string" }
}
if ["tmp"] == "1.1" {
        drop {}
}
mutate {
        remove_field => ["tmp"]
}

Comment: I have been there trying to get along with Logstash.